# Python: Is this the most efficient way to reverse order without using shortcuts?

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#Random list elements
for i in range(int(len(x)/2)):
    value = x[i]
    x[i] = x[len(x)-i-1]
    x[len(x)-i-1] = value
#Confusion on efficiency
print(x)
```

This is a uni course for first year. So no python shortcuts are allowed

Comment: And what is your question? Your code works, if you are asking us to critique this then that's too broad a subject for Stack Overflow. You can post working code on Code Review Stack Exchange to ask for improvements.

Comment: Define shortcut. Is the built-in function reversed a shortcut?

Comment: have you tried: `reversed = x[::-1]` ?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting. Shortcuts are any methods that call exterior functions IE revered, [::-1], etc...
All sorting or editing of list must be done through manual methods ie pop,append,remove,etc...

Comment: indexing in the `[::-1]` way is not calling anything external, since you are doing it on an iterable, its just calling the iterable object's `__getitem__` method. so it is using its own method... the exact same type of method as pop and append.... you can even call this manually by doing something like `x.__getitem__()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what counts as "a shortcut" (`reversed` and the "Martian Smiley" `[::-1]` being obvious candidates -- but does either count as "a shortcut"?!), but at least a couple small improvements are easy:

```
L = len(x)
for i in range(L//2):
     mirror = L - i - 1
     x[i], x[mirror] = x[mirror], x[i]
```

This gets `len(x)` only once -- it's a fast operation but there's no reason to keep repeating it over and over -- also computes `mirror` but once, does the swap more directly, and halves `L` (for the `range` argument) directly with the truncating-division operator rather than using the non-truncating division and then truncating with `int`.  Nanoseconds for each case, but it may be considered slightly clearer as well as microscopically faster.

Comment: Does removing `len(x)` from the `range` call help? Surely that would be evaluated only once either way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but then `len(x)` is called twice more in the OP's version of the code each time through the loop -- so my variant calls it once instead of 2*N+1 times.  (No reason to call it twice when once will do, either -- a nanosecond here, a nanosecond there...:-).

Comment: Ah, of course. `timeit` gives 2.42s vs. 3.77s for `len(x) == 10`, so about a third faster.

Comment: This is perfect, my code was right, but i would like a more efficient understand of the code for self betterment abilities, also any tips to make my posts more positive for the community as to not make it seem like i am such an amateur

Comment: @TehTris, credit for the term goes to my wife (and co-author, and PSF Fellow, and only woman winner so far of the Frank Willison Memorial Award for contributions to the Python community) Anna...

Comment: @Xav, glad to have helped -- the one thing I recommend is to edit your Q to clearly explain what's considered a shortcut (you tried in a comment, but editing the Q is better; also, it's still not clear to me why some indexing, e.g `[::-1]`, is "a shortcut", while other indexing, e.g `[i]`, is "not a shortcut" -- they're both indexing, so where's the divide...?)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x = x.__getitem__(slice(None,None,-1))
```

slice is a python builtin object (like range and len that you used in your example)

`__getitem__` is a method belonging to iterable types ( of which x is)

there are absolutely no shortcuts here :) and its effectively one line.